# Undefined control sequence \url error

Tags: errors, urls, undefined

I got this error while trying to run the `latex` command:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.10 \newblock Available from: \url
                                   {http://www.google.com}.
?
```

Why is it an undefined control sequence?

Comment: Does `\usepackage{url}` help?

Comment: The undefined control sequence is the last token shown in the error line, in this case `\url`.

Comment: I had the same error and searching for my error message resulted in this page as a first hit so this question is indeed relevant, please remove the "closed as too localized" badge.

Comment: The first comment "\usepackage{url}" resolved this problem.

Comment: I second @Gergely.  I had the same error, and this is the first hit.  The first comment `\usepackage{url}` solved my problem.

Comment: @MikaH., on that note, could you please vote to reopen your question?  See [http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question]

Comment: I have a similar error but with `href`, anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: I have `\usepackage{url}` but still got the error. I also had to use `\usepackage{hyperref}`.

Comment: @CGFoX I still have errors even after using `\usepackage{hyperref}` and `\usepackage{url}`.

Comment: check your engine. use `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
\usepackage{url}
```

if you just want the command `\url{}`. If you want hyperlinks, use

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

instead, loading it last (or almost last) in your list of packages. If you'd like nice bookmarks, use

```
\usepackage{bookmark}
```

instead.