# Using xr to refer to another document without hyperref

Tags: cross-referencing, xr

I have two documents A and B. I wish to refer to theorems and lemmas from A in B. To do this I am using the package xr in B.

If I use the package hyperref in B then it's all fine. Otherwise, when I write something like

> from Theorem \ref{thm:1}

it looks like

> from Theorem 1.1theorem1.1

which is not what I wanted. How I do get rid of the "theorem1.1" part at the end? I do not want to use hyperref because I do not want people to click the links in B. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).  Few people really want to have to construct one themselves just to answer the question.

Comment: when switching in either direction between using or not using hyperref you need to delete your .aux files and regenerate both the current and the referenced document. the internal structure of the `\ref` information changes with hyperef.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Package `zref-xr` provides many options for importing references with support of many packages (`hyperref`, `titleref`, ...).

Example file `A.tex` with `hyperref`, which contains the theorems:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
\label{thm:1}
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

File `B.tex` without references imports references from `A`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref-xr}
\zxrsetup{toltxlabel=true, tozreflabel=false}
\zexternaldocument*{A}

\begin{document}
from Theorem \ref{thm:1}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone else:  I was previously using `hyperref`(in my document A as well as B; it's required in A by the publisher).  Removing `hyperref` from the B document and trying `zref-xr` as in @Heiko Oberdiek's solution still gave me some errors:

```
   ! Undefined control sequence.
   l.61 \url{...}`.
```

Some further searching led me to this question:  [Undefined control sequence \url error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85553/undefined-control-sequence-url-error).

Full solution: adding `\usepackage{url}` made the first solution (@Heiko Oberdiek) work like a charm.

```
\usepackage{zref-xr}
\zxrsetup{toltxlabel=true, tozreflabel=false}
\zexternaldocument*{A}
\usepackage{url}  %Need to make doc B work with URL links in the bibtex file
```